# Realtime JSON feed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, json, real-time

Wondering if there is a way to read and access realtime JSON data within QGIS. I am aware of how to work with realtime GeoJSON, however I would like to work with JSON data, which does have lat/long coordinates, like in the link provided below. The ultimate goal is to access realtime data within QGIS. Is there any such tool like what is available to work with CSV data to convert to geo, but that will allow for realtime updates?

https://tor.publicbikesystem.net/ube/gbfs/v1/en/station_information

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is run a thread in the embedded python console. 
In the following example, I use a thread that refreshes all the layers every 10 000 ms.

https://github.com/danieldemonceau/0049_SYDNEY_FERRIES/blob/master/python/01.REFRESH_QGIS.py

In your case, you could develop a routine that reads the json and converts it to a layer. The thread would fire that process every xx 000ms